# Lambda on_success destination to EventBridge is failing silently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda with an eventbridge rule as the trigger and the same event bridge bus as it's on success destination. I have all the permissions set to put events on the bus and have verified this by manually calling boto3 put events from the lambda. But the response from the lambda is not landing on the bus. There is no errors or failed invocations on the monitors. Is there any known issues with using the eventbridge as a lambda destination.

The way I tested it, I have two eventbridge rules one that invokes the lambda and the other that logs the expected lambda's response. I put an event on the bus and verify that it logs what I expect from the lambda, I then check the other logs which show no activity. If change the lambda to call boto3 to make the put event request then the logs fire like I expect. I use the `detail-type` param to match for the event pattern.

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function being invoked synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: Async with the eventbridge as the trigger. The same bus is the destination

Comment: Disclosure: EventBridge PM here. Can you please reach out to your AWS support so we can troubleshoot this in detail?